# When to use a whole vector approach vs an energy approach?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, vectors

My professor has just introduced two new ways to solve projectile motions. One approach involve using trigonometry and vectors and the other involves using the idea of conservation of energy. My question is, in what situations would the vector approach instead of the energy approach be more useful and vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually infer the difference of the approaches just by looking at their names. A vector has direction and an energy (a scalar quantity) does not. Therefore, when you are trying to figure out scalar quantities such as distance and speed, you may find energy method more advantageous; when you look for velocity, acceleration, you have to use vector approach.

Here is a simple example. Consider a cliff that is 80 m high, you shoot a projectile at speed 12 m/s, and at an inclination angle of 45 degrees. I will classify the following questions into vector and energy approaches:

1. Find the speed of projectile when it hits the ground. (energy)
2. Find the velocity of the projectile when it hits the ground. (vector)
3. Find the maximum height reached by the projectile. (energy)

I hope the hypothetical situation above provides some intuition.